# Branch.io deep link open google play in the browser

Tags: android, branch.io

I'm using the web branch.io sdk in order to generate a deep link.

I have configured the app, I think properly, in branch.io for android:

- Android URI Scheme
- Using google play search as fallback

In js creating the data object

```
data: {
                '$desktop_url': content.shareUrl,
                '$android_url': androidURL,
                "$always_deeplink": true,
                '$ios_url': iosURL,
                '$og_title': content.name,
                '$og_description': content.description,
                'content_locator_key': content.url
            }
```

Where androidUrl is the url to google play as https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xxxxxxx

The problem is that that link, in android, ALWAYS redirect to the app store, but, in the browser, in Chrome, and in the webpage said that the app is installed in the device.

What is wrong? Why the app store is oponed in the browser instead of the google play applicatino in the mobile? And, if google play says that the app is installed, why the application is not opened directly?

I cannot figure out the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to integrate Branch SDk in mobile.
2. When you click on a given branch link from mobile, it should redirect to app,        if app is installed.
3. On App Open, you need to make a call or receive branch data, and need to write a login to perform required action (i.e. navigating to Product details etc.)

Refer [this](https://branch.io/how-branch-links-work/) for more clarification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: this is correct. You need to have the Branch SDK inside your app for it to open

Comment: Alex Hi. On Samsung when a link is clicked it opens in the Samsung default browser. and then again we have to click on the menu(three dots on top right corner) and then select open in the browser. How to handle this? how to skip this and directly open the app when a link is clicked?